# how to hook for destroy of a model that belongs to another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip

I have a User model which has_many experiments:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :experiments, :dependent => :destroy
```

and Experiment model:

```
class Experiment < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
has_attached_file :thumbnail
```

I want to hook for destroy moment at the Experiment model after the owner User get destroyed. (ex user cancel his account)

I need to do so to delete the attachment image of the Experiment model, which is stored at amazon. like `experiment.thumbnail.destroy`

What is the recommended way to accomplish this?

**EDIT**

Although I have destroyed the thumbnail with no errors, but, the file is still not removed! i can still see it at amazon bucket

```
class Experiment < ActiveRecord::Base
before_destroy :remove_attachment

def remove_attachment
    self.thumbnail.destroy
    puts self.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
    true
end
```

After I destroy the experiment, remove_attachment is called, but errors.full_messages are empty! so there is no errors, but, still the file is not deleted at the buck

Any idea ??

Comment: Paperclip will by default remove the files when the associated record (Experiment in your case) is deleted. If that does not happen then it sound like there is some problem with your Amazon S3 (Only guessing that you are using S3 by your usage of the word bucket) configuration. Have you checked your logfiles (production.log or development.log) for additional information?

Comment: But my settings is working properly when uploading a file, its just deleting is not working, and I couldn't find any thing in the log files .. where to look now ?

Comment: Hard to say. In your question you don't list the parameters for your call to `has_attached_file`. Can you add that? For example, there is a configuration option called :preserve_file that is false by default and should in your case remain so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to hook for destroy moment at the Experiment model after the
>   owner User get destroyed.

```
has_many :experiments, :dependent => :destroy
```

already does that.

To remove the attachment, I recommend using a callback

```
class Experiment < ActiveRecord::Base

    before_destroy { |experiment| experiment.thumbnail.destroy }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a [callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) like:

`before_destroy :delete_attachment_image`