# How to remove image from amzon in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I used the paperclip module with amazon s3 server for storing images.

I can uploaded an image successfully with below line.

**album_photo.avatar.url(:original)**

But how can I delete this image from S3? I don't know how.

I call a simple destroy method like below:

```
def destroy
  @album.destroy    
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

But it only delete the image from the DB not from S3.

I referred to [Paperclip - delete a file from Amazon S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450530/paperclip-delete-a-file-from-amazon-s3) link but I don't understand.

So what am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435826/rails-paperclip-how-to-delete-attachment

Comment: just delete that activerecord ..paperclip will automatically delete from AWS.For associated models.it will work too if you have added dependent: destroy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try** ,it should automatically delete it.

`<%= link_to "delete your photo", photo_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }%>`