# How to call an `f.action` to a custom :delete callback in an Active Admin form

Tags: paperclip, activeadmin, formtastic

In order to remove (paperclip) images from my objects, I have a custom callback (and route) defined:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Camping do
  #...
  member_action :destroy_image, :method => :delete do
    camping = Camping.find(params[:id])
    camping.image.destroy
    redirect_to({:action => :show}, :notice => "Image deleted")
  end
end
```

This works as expected; trough a named route `destroy_image_admin_camping => /admin/campings/:id/destroy_image`.

The problem is that I cannot find how to add this to the form:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Camping do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Camping" do
      f.input :name
      f.input :image
      f.action :delete_image, :url => destroy_image_admin_camping_path(@camping.id), :button_html => { :method => :delete }
      f.input :description
    end

    f.actions
  end
  #...
 end
```

More detailed: I don't know how to pass the "id of the current item we are editing" into `destroy_image_admin_camping_path`; `@camping` is nil, `f.camping` not defined and so I don't know how to pass the item in there.

Is this the right approach? I prefer this "ajax-ish" interface over a more common checkbox-that-deletes-images-on-update, but I am not sure if this will work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few questions here, I'll try to address them all.

**How to access the "id of the current item we are editing"**

You are pretty close in looking for `f.camping`. What you want is `f.object`, so:

`destroy_image_admin_camping_path(f.object.id)`.

NOTE: `f.object.id` will be `nil` when it's a new form (as opposed to an edit form), you'll want to check for that with `unless f.object.new_record?`

**"Is this the right approach?"**

I'm not sure, really. To me it seems like making requests without actually saving the currently rendered form could create complications, but it might turn out to be a better interface. Anyway, if you want to do the checkbox-that-deletes-images-on-update, this should help you out: [Rails Paperclip how to delete attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435826/rails-paperclip-how-to-delete-attachment).

However, if you want the ajax-ish approach I think you'll want an `<a>` tag styled as a button. The problem with actually using a button is that you don't want to submit the form.

Here's an example:

```rb
f.inputs do
  link_to 'Delete Image', delete_image_admin_camping_path(f.object.id), class: 'button', remote: true, method: :delete
end
```

`remote: true` will make it an ajax request and ActiveAdmin gives you a pretty reasonable button class for `<a>` tags. Updating the interface based on success / failure is left as an exercise to the reader.

Also, you'll probably want to use erb templates for this instead of the Active Admin DSL (see http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html at the bottom).

Like this:

```rb
# app/views/admin/campings/_form.html.erb

<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @post] do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :image %>
    <%# Actually, you might want to check for presence of the image, I don't know Paperclip well enough to demonstrate that though %>
    <% unless f.object.new_record? %>
      <%= image_tag f.object.image_url %>
      <%= link_to 'Delete Image', delete_image_admin_camping_path(f.object.id), class: 'button', remote: true, method: :delete %>
    <% end %>

    ...

  <% end %>

  <%= f.actions %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: NOTE: For updating the interface after rails ajax requests, take a look at the jquery-ujs list of ajax events: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax