# Undefined method field in rails while adding delete option in paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to add delete option in paperclip . And kind of followed the link to delete

[Rails Paperclip how to delete attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435826/rails-paperclip-how-to-delete-attachment)

My model class is

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :post
   attr_accessible :image 
   attr_accessor :image_delete
   before_save :destroy_image?
   has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "640x480>", 
                                     :thumb => "100x100#"},

   :storage => :s3,
   :s3_credentials => {
     :access_key_id => ENV['K1'],
     :secret_access_key => ENV['K2']
   },
   :path => ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
   :bucket => 'test_local'

 private
    def destroy_image?
    self.image.clear if @image_delete == "1"
 end
end
```

And my form snippet is

```
 <h4>Show Old Images</h4>
```

```
      <% unless asset_fields.object.new_record? %>
              <%= link_to image_tag(asset_fields.object.image.url(:thumb)) %>
               <%#= asset_fields.object.delete_asset %>
              <%= f.check_box asset_fields.file_field :image_delete, :label => 'Delete Image'%>                                             
      <% end %>
```

The error is get

```
undefined method 
<input id="post_assets_attributes_1_image_delete" label="Delete Image" name="post[assets_attributes][1][image_delete]" type="file" />' for #<Post:0x00000104e770c0>
```

Whats the issue

Answer (score 0):

The way i resolved is 
change

```
<%= f.check_box asset_fields.file_field :image_delete, :label => 'Delete Image'%>
```

to

```
<%= asset_fields.check_box asset_fields.file_field :image_delete, :label => 'Delete Image'%>
```