# Deleting a public folder or file from a Rails3 view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have a user model where users can upload their profile image, using the Paperclip gem. This all works fine and stores the file in the `/public/images/#{user.id}/medium` or original or small directory.

However I need to create an method to be able to delete these files, could someone help me with this?

Here is the code I have so far:

app/views/users/index.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", method: :file_cleanup, action: :destroy %>
```

app/controllers/users_controllers.rb:

```
def file_cleanup
    File.delete(Rails.root + 'public/#{current_user.image.url}')
    redirect_to :action => :edit
end
```

I have not added any routes as the page seems to load without any errors.

Comment: you will need to change your `link_to` to this: `<%= link_to "Delete", controller: "users", action: "file_cleanup" %>`

Comment: that gives a route error "No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"file_cleanup"}"

Comment: Have you set this route up in your `routes` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
def delete_image
  @user.image.destroy
end
```

I'd use that as a hook like `before_destroy :delete_image`.

See:  [Rails Paperclip how to delete attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435826/rails-paperclip-how-to-delete-attachment)

Comment: How simple! Thank you so much, sometimes I forget that Ruby/Rails is actually so kind to its developers. Thank you very much for your help and your prompt reply :)

Comment: @user2339235 If it did help, please close this question by clicking the checkbox next to this answer. :)