# Ruby On Rails: nested attributes update on demmand

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, nested-forms

I'm building a form with nested attributes (accepts_nested_attributes_for). One of the nested models uses paperclip. I'm developing the following solution for deleting attachments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8062259/503141

The problem I face is that, when the main object is saved, the nested model is only saved if the submodel has changed and the avobe solution does not work.

Is there any how to change this behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nested models are saved according to changed? method. Therefore you need to overwrite changed? method accordingly. In this case would be:

```
  def changed?
    (photo_delete == '1') || super
  end
```