# Paperclip, before_save, and deleting attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, before-save

I can't get this `before_save` filter to work. My methods are pretty standard, I think. Images are uploaded via Paperclip.

```
before_save :remove_checked_attachments

def attachments
  %w(banner footer logo accreditation)
end

private

def remove_checked_attachments
  attachments.each do |a|
    if "remove_#{a}".to_sym && !"#{a}_updated_at_changed?".to_sym
      "#{a}".to_sym.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

The `remove_...` params are passed, nothing's deleted though:

```
... "remove_banner"=>"1" ...
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

**Update**

Even simplifying it to this doesn't work:

```
after_validation { banner.clear if remove_banner == '1' }
```

And `"remove_banner"=>"1"` comes through in the params. The `u.banner.clear` then `u.banner.save` works fine in the console.

Comment: When you `destroy` the `#{a}`.to_sym - where is that data stored? Is it in the db already, or part of the params hash?

Comment: `#{a}` represents each Paperclip attachment in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by making a concern like so:

```
# must be included after attachment declarations in model
module RemoveAttachment
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    attachment_definitions.keys.each do |name|

      attr_accessible :"remove_#{name}"
      attr_accessor :"remove_#{name}"

      before_validation { send(name).destroy if send("remove_#{name}") == '1' }

      define_method :"remove_#{name}=" do |value|
        instance_variable_set :"@remove_#{name}", value
        send("#{name}_file_name_will_change!")
      end

    end
  end
end
```

And just including the concern wherever need be. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23908552/1342734) answer for a huge clue.