# How can I remove Paperclip attachment using link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I've found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435826/rails-paperclip-how-to-delete-attachment) that uses a checkbox as a flag to delete the image. However, I want to use a `link_to`. Basically, next to the image attachment, I want to have a "Delete Avatar" link. If possible, I want the link to only delete the image, and not update the other attributes.

User class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar
  attr_accessible :avatar
```

In the form

```
link_to "Delete Avatar", {:action => :update}, :method => :put
```

Obviously this doesn't actually delete the image just yet. What would be the best way to do this? Have the link set a hidden flag and then update? Or is this just a bad idea (if so why)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a patch route to remove attachment with user_id and matching action in the controller

```
link_to 'Delete Avatar', {action: :action_name, id: user.id}, method: :put

def action_name
  # use either/or depending on your usecase
  @user.avatar.destroy #Will remove the attachment and save the model
  @user.avatar.clear #Will queue the attachment to be deleted
end
```